# On mobile devices stop top of 5th row from showing when first 4 rows are hidden

Tags: html, jquery, css

I have a [website](https://talkanxiety.com/) which shows a number of user entered stories. Only the first 4 rows are shown of each story with a fading text gradient from black to white. There is a show more/less button. This works well on a laptop, but when I view it on my phone (OnePlus 7T) I can see the very top of the 5th row, which looks like a number of black dots. I wan't to stop this from happening.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".content").on("click", '.showMore', function() {

    var $this = $(this);
    var content = $this.prev()
    var linkText = $this.text().toUpperCase();
    
    if (linkText === "MORE") {
      linkText = "Less";
      $this.siblings('div').css('height', 'auto');
      var currHeight = $this.siblings('div').height();
       $this.siblings('div').css('height', '8em');
       $this.siblings('div').animate({height: currHeight}, 500);
        $this.parent('div').addClass('fullpost');
   } else {
       $this.siblings('div').animate({height: '8em'}, 500);

       $this.parent('div').removeClass('fullpost');
      linkText = "More";
    }    
$this.html( "<a>" + linkText + "</a>" );  
  });
});
```

```
<div class="content">
  <div class="post">
    <div class="hideContent">
        <div class="post-text"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam blandit a ipsum nec pharetra. Donec eget tempus neque. Vestibulum sit amet sollicitudin ligula. Sed viverra odio nec augue fermentum condimentum. Etiam dapibus urna sit amet sagittis lobortis. Maecenas ut nisi et leo facilisis pellentesque. Pellentesque sed lacus nulla. Morbi auctor quam et neque fermentum, quis congue erat viverra. Aliquam aliquam vulputate lorem, euismod scelerisque augue finibus eu. Suspendisse efficitur bibendum nibh, blandit finibus sapien eleifend a. Vestibulum bibendum augue augue, nec dictum nisi posuere a.
       </div>
    </div>
  <div class="showMore"><a>Show more</a></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

```
.post-text::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 2em;
    left: 0;
    height: 90px;
    width: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), white);
}

.fullpost .post-text::after {
  height:0;
  background: none;
}

.post-text{
    position: relative;;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    line-height: 2;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: Times, serif;
    color: #000000;
    text-align: justify;
}

.hideContent {
  overflow: hidden;
  line-height: 1em;
  height: 8em;
}

.showContent {
  line-height: 1em;
  height: auto;
}

.showMore {
  margin-top: -8px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  color: #1ca099;
  font-weight: bold;
  /*text-decoration: underline;*/
}
```

Comment: you could simply add `max-height: 100px` to your `hideContent` class.

Comment: Thank you @Mech. When I do this it hides some of the More button as well. Why do you set it to 100px?

Comment: You're welcome. 100px was the number I was using when testing. I see you used 128px. Add `margin-bottom: 10px` to the `hideContent` class as well and see if you like the way it looks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `max-height` and `margin-bottom` to your `hideContent` class to limit the size of the `div` container and move the "More" link down a touch.

```
.hideContent {
  overflow: hidden;
  line-height: 1em;
  height: 8em;
  max-height: 128px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. So I've amended it to 124px now and that hides it both on the laptop and mobile device great. But now the show More button doesn't show all the story when pressed because the max-height has been set to 124px.

Comment: I see. Let's see what we can do about that.

Comment: Why not just change the class itself rather than pieces of a class? Or set max-height to none when showing content.

Comment: You'll also want to do 122px since a 3 line post will show the top of "Like"

Comment: thanks. I'll make those changes. Have a good evening. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Glad to assist!